# Why does my procedural grid mesh not triangulate properly for grids bigger than 256x256?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, procedural-generation

I've been making procedural terrain height maps with the diamond square algorithm and the mesh with the triangulation method below:

```
        public Map GenerateMap()
        {
            Mesh mapMesh = new();

            vertices = new Vector3[(Resolution + 1) * (Resolution + 1)];
            Vector2[] uv1 = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
            Vector2[] uv2 = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
            Vector2[] uv3 = new Vector2[vertices.Length];
            DiamondSquare diamondSquare = new(Resolution, Roughness, Seed, HeightLevels);
            float[,] heightFloatMap = diamondSquare.DoDiamondSquare();
            tex = new Texture2D(Resolution, Resolution);

            for (int y = 0, i = 0; y <= Resolution; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x <= Resolution; x++, i++)
                {
                    //float height = heightMap.GetPixel(x,y).r;
                    float height = heightFloatMap[x, y];
                    vertices[i] = new Vector3(x * CellSize.x, height * CellSize.y, y * CellSize.z);
                    tex.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(height, height, height, 1));
                    if (height == 0)
                        uv1[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].z);
                    else if (height < 0.4)
                        uv2[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].z);
                    else if (height < 0.4)
                        uv3[i] = new Vector2(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].z);
                }
            }
            mapMesh.vertices = vertices;
            mapMesh.uv = uv1;
            mapMesh.uv2 = uv2;

            int[] triangles = new int[Resolution * Resolution * 6];
            Cell[,] cellMap = new Cell[Resolution / 4, Resolution / 4];
            for (int ti = 0, vi = 0, y = 0; y < Resolution; y++, vi++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Resolution; x++, ti += 6, vi++)
                {
                    triangles[ti] = vi;
                    triangles[ti + 3] = triangles[ti + 2] = vi + 1;
                    triangles[ti + 4] = triangles[ti + 1] = vi + Resolution + 1;
                    triangles[ti + 5] = vi + Resolution + 2;

                    Vector3[] cellVerts = new Vector3[]
                        {
                            vertices[vi], vertices[vi + 1], vertices[vi + Resolution + 1], vertices[vi + Resolution + 2]
                        };
                    Cell cell = new(new Vector2Int(x, y), cellVerts, CalculateCellGeometry(cellVerts));
                    cellMap[x / 4, y / 4] = cell;
                }
            }
            mapMesh.triangles = triangles;

            mapMesh.RecalculateNormals();
            mapMesh.RecalculateTangents();
            mapMesh.RecalculateBounds();

            Map map = new(mapMesh, cellMap, heightFloatMap, vertices);
            return map;
        }
    }
```

This works fine with grid sizes 16x16, 32x32... 256x256 but breaks when I try it on 512x512 or above

256x256

[Mesh is perfect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nyUC.jpg)

512x512

[It successfully triangulates up until the rows starting y=128](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzXU3.jpg)

[On the underside of the terrain there are these bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VvsVi.png)

I've mapped out the vertices generated from 512x512 and above resolutions and they are all good so I'm 99% sure its down to the triangulation.

I'm new to procedural meshes and am stumped by this issue, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ryan, welcome to SO. This site is not for debugging your code, but I think your question could be rephrased to make it more useful to other developers. "I'm generating a mesh (a heightfield as detailed below). I get this error: <specific error> when I use large vertex count (above <specific N>). What would cause that error?"

Comment: The code I posted doesn't generate any errors so even if I knew that I wouldn't have been able to. I've found multiple other threads with answers that follow the same structure as mine so I assumed it was fine.

Comment: I'll rephrase my question in that format next time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it wasn't triangulation, the vertex limit was being reached as my mesh was set to use a 16-bit index buffer.

I added this line

```
mapMesh.indexFormat = UnityEngine.Rendering.IndexFormat.UInt32;
```

and the issue is fixed. An annoying oversight on my part but that's part of the learning process!